# color package and page number, header, footnote

Tags: color

In the following minimal example, I am using the "color" package
to get a blue color for the entire document including page numbering, header, footnote, footnote mark, etc. But, the page numbers, page headers, and footnote mark symbols all come only in black color. 
 How to get "everything" in blue color?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\color{blue}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\tableofcontents
\vfill\eject

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{ONE}

This is a footnote in blue color\footnote{ \color{blue} blue color}
This is a second footnote\footnote{second footnote}.
\lipsum
\chapter{TWO}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You may need to declare color for these definitions (`\ps@headings`, `\ps@plain`, `\@makefntext`, `\footnoterule`)

Comment: @KumareshPS no, that isn't needed

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, Its my bad. Thanks for updating.

Answer (score 3):

The page numbers are set in the document default colour which is the colour in force at `\begin{docuemnt}` so just move the `\color` up a line.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\color{blue}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\tableofcontents
\vfill\eject

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{ONE}

This is a footnote in blue color\footnote{ \color{blue} blue color}
This is a second footnote\footnote{second footnote.}
\lipsum
\chapter{TWO}
\end{document}
```